# What's the deal with the fertilizer in RAD?

Tags: rad

When I play RAD my guy leaves a trail of flowers behind it, which is useful for keeping track where I already have been. Is there something else to it? Occasionally I get this mutation, which makes a broader spread of it? Does this serve any purpose beyond eyecandy?
I mean, it looks nice if I can spread it on scorched earth, but there doesn't seem to be any other purpose to it.